# Is it possible to have a class as your model field in Django?

Tags: django, model, field

I am currently trying to create a health network website in Django. 
The idea is that there will be a class called User inside my registration application. One of the states stored inside User is which hospital the user is registered into.

I created another Hospital within the registration app. I want to user that model Hospital as one of the model field for the hospital_used state. How do I do that? Below is a portion of my UML that illustrates the relationship
[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Cic.)

[Below is a portion of my UML that illustrates the relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Cic.)
png

Here is the code I have for it so far. The code where it is encapsulated with an asterisk is what I need help with.

```
class Hospital(models.Model):
    hospital_Name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Hospital Name: " + str(self.hospital_Name)


class User(models.Model):
    PATIENT = 'Pat'
    DOCTOR = 'Doc'
    NURSE = 'Nurse'
    ADMINISTRATOR = 'Admin'
    user_type_choice = {
        (PATIENT, 'Patient'),
        (DOCTOR, 'Doctor'),
        (NURSE, 'Nurse'),
        (ADMINISTRATOR, 'Administrator'),
    }

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    *preferred_hospital = Hospital(models.CharField(max_length=50))*
    patient_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        choices=user_type_choice,
    )
```

Thank you StackOverflow Buddies

Comment: Simply use a foreign key.

Comment: wow, ok yeah thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to read this material [on tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/) on how to create simple models.

What you want here is to use the ForeignKey method.

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
preferred_hospital = models.ForeignKey(Hospital, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
patient_type = models.CharField(
    max_length=5,
    choices=user_type_choice,
)
```

You do not have to use `on_delete = models.CASCADE` but it is best that you handle what should happen when you delete an Hospital.

Know that you can also have OneToOne, ManyToOne, or ManyToMany fields, that are all described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/).